# Could someone please tell me how to get rid of the gridlines on all of the excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, gridlines

I have tried many time but i have not able to do that, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple with VBA. To remove gridlines from your sheet, set the DisplayGridlines property of the Window Object to False.

Check out this article for more information: https://www.automationfever.com/vba/vba_remove_gridlines.php

You can learn how to remove gridlines from your sheet in VBA by watching the video below : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP6Y9WMwQUU

Comment: You say: *To **remove** gridlines from your sheet, set the `DisplayGridlines` property of the Window Object to **true**.* Perhaps you meant to say the opposite?